# What is the complete list of Gauss's contributions to topology and knot theory?

Tags: biographical-details

I read in Gauss's biography - Gauss:Titan of Science, in the section "milestones" that "in particular, he found in a note dated December, 1844, the numerous forms which closed curves with four knots can exhibit". What's the meaning of this sentence? does it mean that he found the number of links which four knots of a certain kind can create? Where is it in his nachlass?